# Ask user for 10 numbers, tell which one was the least number

Tags: java, loops

I am doing an exercise where I ask the user, 10  numbers (to represent their 10 best friends weights. And I am supposed to state which number they entered was the least.

I am sort of new to doing loops, so I tried doing a for loop. Should I change it to a do while instead?

And here is my code. I tried to make a previous weight variable and if the weight is less than the previous weight number, then the weight will become the new lowest weight. But I don't think it is working properly because it is saying the lowest was 0, so I would assume the problem is somewhere where the previous weight and weight variables messed up.

And I do see that they are assigned to the same value because they are equal to each other, BUT I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO FIX THIS! I tried putting previous total at the top of the loop but then I would need to initialize the variable which defies the purpose of it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ExtraProblem13 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double low = 0;
        double weight;
        double previousWeight;
        String sWeight;

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i ++) {
            System.out.print("Enter your best friend # " + i + "'s weight: ");
            sWeight = input.nextLine();
            weight = Double.parseDouble(sWeight);
            previousWeight = weight;
            if (weight < previousWeight) {
                low = weight;
            }
        }
        input.close();
        System.out.println("The lowest weight that you entered was " + low);
    }

}
```

Comment: You set `previousWeight = weight` and then you are comparing them?? It'll never be true

Comment: How can I change it? So that I am able to compare them?

Comment: You don't need previous weight, just compare it directly to low.  Also make low start at max int, so the first choice is always stored there, otherwise 0 will always be the lowest.

Comment: Remove that  equals line

Comment: I see but how do I start with max int?

Comment: You should use input.nextDouble() instead of nextLine() and then getting double out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:-

```
 Double min=0;
 for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i ++) {
    System.out.print("Enter your best friend # " + i + "'s weight: ");
    sWeight = input.nextLine();
    weight = Double.parseDouble(sWeight);
    if(i==1){
      min=weight;
     }
else if(min>weight){
min=weight;
}
}
```

min will have the lowest weight at the end of program.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

You are assigning the vlue of *weight* to *previousWeight* before comparing them. S the condition if(weight < previousWeight) is useless.

**Solution**

No need to use seperate variable previousWeight. Use **low** to store the minimum number entered yet and update it if any lower vlue for **weight** is entered. Also use nextDouble() instead of nextLine(), it will save the energy needed to convert it into double :-p

**Code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ExtraProblem13 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double low;
        double weight;

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        low = 9999; //some large number
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i ++) {
            System.out.print("Enter your best friend # " + i + "'s weight: ");
            Weight = input.nextDouble();    
            if (weight < low) {
                low = weight;
            }
        }
        input.close();
        System.out.println("The lowest weight that you entered was " + low);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare this with your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ExtraProblem13 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double low = Double.MAX_VALUE; // You want to set this to a high number
        double weight;

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i ++) {
            System.out.print("Enter your best friend # " + i + "'s weight: ");
            weight = input.nextDouble();

            if (weight < low) {
                low = weight;
            }
        }
        input.close();
        System.out.println("The lowest weight that you entered was " + low);
    }

}
```

Further optimization can be applied, and code can be enhanced but this is outside the scope of this question.